# How can I switch between two div depending upon the value of a scope variable?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an issue that I **want to switch between two divs depending upon value of a scope variable**. The scope variable is updated at run time and I want my view to be updated at run time.

The problem is that **the view gets loaded with initial value of scope variable and scope variable's value gets changed at run time but the view is not effected**.

Here is a sample code:

**HTML**

```
<div **ng-if="pending=='done'"**> <!-- No Records Found -->
   <div>
        <center><h2> You have not any contacts yet. </h2>
   </div>
</div>                       
<div>
  <table **ng-if="pending=='not done'"**> 
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>E-mail</th>
          <th>Contact Number</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="(Id, value) in user.Count ng-if="value.status=='Approved'">
        <td> {{Id}} </td>
        <td> {{value.name}} </td>
        <td> {{value.email}} </td>
        <td> {{value.phone}} </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div ng-init="changescopevalue()">
  changing scope now
</div>
```

**Function in CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.pending = "done";

$scope.changescopevalue = function() {
  $scope.pending = "not done";
};
```

So the div with **[ng-if="pending=='done'"]** loads then the scope variable changes to **"not done"** but the view is uneffected.

Please help..

Thanks.

Comment: Did you already try with ng-show="..." or ng-hide ?

Comment: do you mind setting up a plunker so we can play around with your example?

Comment: yes brother it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid `ng-init`. From [angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) :

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

You forgot to close the `<center>` tag, but you better not use it, as it is deprecated. Use css instead. Also, your `ng-repeat` value is missing quotes `"`, it should be :

```
ng-repeat="(Id, value) in user.Count" ng-if="value.status=='Approved'"
```

Aside that, your `ng-if` based on the value of the scope variable `pending` works well, if you setted up angular correctly :

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/micaz/efxn57qo/1/)